# how to Initialize a csv file in jmeter via Simple table server

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

i am able to initialize a CSV file via Simple table server when file is in jmeter bin folder.

as per requirement i need to initialize CSV file from a different location, i tried multiple ways but i am getting error as "Error : Illegal character found !"

file location: C:/sample/sample.csv

please suggest solution how to handle this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#INITFILE) states:

> The filename is limited to 128 characters maxi and must not contains characters \ / : or ..
>
> This limits are for security reasons (E.g: NOT read "/etc/passwd" or ../../../tomcat/conf/server.xml).

Instead of passing the full path to the file you should rather set the following [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization):

```
jmeterPlugin.sts.datasetDirectory=C:/sample
```

and use just `sample.csv` in the `INTIFILE` command.